# R Highcharter - how to select series with checkboxes in popup?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

The Highcharts default legend is clickable, dynamically showing/hiding each series clicked. But for charts with many series, this isn't good for user experience. Is there some way to include all available series in a popup with checkboxes, like [this chart](https://ourworldindata.org/food-supply#caloric-supply-by-region) from owid?

Specifically, is there a way to achieve this using the R highcharter package?

Comment: Could you please share some code you have tried and reproducible data using `dput`?